# How can I generate a string of set amount of numbers from these 2 arrays?

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I have `String[] private_array;` and `String[] public_array;` defined in my project.

`private_array` is a sequence of numbers, of no set amount (sometimes more numbers, sometimes less), like, `[105, 21, 57, 60, 103, 108, 111, 113, 116, 173, 104]`

Likewise, `public_array` is a sequence of numbers, of no set amount, like, `[102, 44, 3]`

I want to make a new String, `mixture_array`, that will contain a total of 10 non-repeating numbers, made from numbers in `private_array` and `public_array`. These 10 numbers should be made from `private_array`, firstly, but if there are less than 10 numbers in `private_array`, then numbers from `public_array` should make up the difference.

How I can do this?

Right now I have two methods, `getPrivateRandomNumbers();` and `getPublicRandomNumbers();` that give me non-repeating numbers from each string array. (however, my activity does not load properly if an array contains less than 10 numbers, I'm sure it's to do with the '11' part)

```
  private Integer[] getPrivateRandomNumbers() {
    HashSet<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>(11);
    Random random = new Random();
    while (integers.size() < 11) {
      // add number generation logic below
      integers.add(Integer.parseInt(private_array[random.nextInt(private_array.length)]));
    }

    private_array_numbers = integers.toArray(new Integer[11]);

    return private_array_numbers;
  }



 private Integer[] getPublicRandomNumbers() {
    HashSet<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>(11);
    Random random = new Random();
    while (integers.size() < 11) {
      // add number generation logic below
      integers.add(Integer.parseInt(public_array[random.nextInt(public_array.length)]));
    }

    public_array_numbers = integers.toArray(new Integer[11]);

    return public_array_numbers;
  }
```

And from the above I can get:

```
mixture_array = (Arrays.toString(private_array_numbers) + Arrays.toString(public_array_numbers));
```

How could I fuse the two arrays together, to make `mixture_array` in the way I'm looking for?

Comment: so you want on  array of 10 random non repeating numbers from those two arrays you defined?

Comment: Yes, but it could be less than 10 if the 2 arrays don't make up the numbers.

Comment: you want to merge two arrays that are returned?

Comment: Are there duplicates in one array?

Comment: No duplicates in any of the 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have assured that there will be no duplicates in any of the 2 arrays in the comments, I would recommend to

- first convert the two arrays to list,
- shuffel them both to get the elements in a random order,
- add all shuffeld elements from your `private_array` to a result list,
- iterate over the shuffeld list of your `public_array` and add each to
  result list if it doesn't already exist and
- finally return a sublist of result countaining the amount of strings 
  needed.

Example:

```
public static String[] getMixedRandomNumbers(int size) {
    String[] private_array = {"105", "21", "57", "60", "103", "108", "111", "113", "116", "173", "104"};
    String[] public_array  = {"103", "44", "3"};
    List<String> priv = Arrays.asList(private_array);
    List<String> publ = Arrays.asList(public_array);
    Collections.shuffle(priv);
    Collections.shuffle(publ);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.addAll(priv);
    for(String p : publ){
        if(!result.contains(p)){
            result.add(p);
        }
    }        
    int i = Math.min(size, result.size());
    return result.subList(0, i).toArray(new String[i]);
}
```

Comment: Trying to run this code but right now .stream() is causing problems, only accessible on Java 8.

Comment: @CHarris I have edited my answer and removed the stream part.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
static String[] private_array = new String[]{"105", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "60", "103", "108", "111", "111", "116", "173", "104"};

static String[] public_array = new String[]{"103", "44", "104"};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> privateArr = Arrays.asList(private_array);
    List<String> publicArr = Arrays.asList(public_array);

    List<String> nonDuplicatedPrivate = getNonDuplicated(privateArr, publicArr, new ArrayList<>());
    getNonDuplicated(publicArr, privateArr, nonDuplicatedPrivate);
}

private static List<String> getNonDuplicated(List<String> toIterate, List<String> other, List<String> accumulator) {
    for (int i = 0; i < toIterate.size() && accumulator.size() < 10; i++) {
        String currentElement = toIterate.get(i);
        if (!other.contains(currentElement) && toIterate.indexOf(currentElement) == i && toIterate.lastIndexOf(currentElement) == i) {
            accumulator.add(currentElement);
        }
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see this will just list the same values of the array every time?